# I am using UART0 with interrupts and when I write any character in the UART window, it didn't jump to the handler

Tags: arm, embedded, texas-instruments

## here is the UART0_Init() function

```
`void UART_Init(void){
   uint8_t ss;
    // as part of Lab 11, modify this program to use UART0 instead of UART1
  //                 switching from PC5,PC4 to PA1,PA0
     SET_BIT_PERIPH_BAND(SYSCTRL->RCGCUART,SYSCTL_RCGC1_UART0);// activate UART0
     SET_BIT_PERIPH_BAND(SYSCTRL->RCGCGPIO,SYSCTL_RCGC2_GPIOA);// activate port A
      ss =0;
      ss =0;
     CLEAR_BIT_PERIPH_BAND(UART0->CTL,UART_CTL_UARTEN);// disable UART
    CLEAR_BIT_PERIPH_BAND(UART0->ICR,UART_ICR_RXIC); 
    UART0->IBRD = 43;                                                  // IBRD = int(80,000,000 / (16 * 115200)) = int(43.402778)
     UART0->FBRD = 26;                    // FBRD = round(0.402778 * 64) = 26                                  // 8 bit word length (no parity bits, one stop bit, FIFOs)
     UART0->LCRH = (UART_LCRH_WLEN_8|UART_LCRH_FEN);
     SET_BIT_PERIPH_BAND(UART0->CTL ,UART_CTL_RXE);
    SET_BIT_PERIPH_BAND(UART0->CTL ,UART_CTL_TXE);
    SET_BIT_PERIPH_BAND(UART0->CTL ,UART_CTL_UARTEN);// enable UART
     SET_BIT_PERIPH_BAND(UART0->IM,UART_IM_RXIM);
    SET_BIT_PERIPH_BAND(UART0->IM,UART_IM_TXIM);
    GPIOA->GPIOAFSEL |= 0x03;           // enable alt funct on PA1,PA0
     GPIOA->GPIODEN |= 0x03;             // enable digital I/O on PA1,PA0
                                        // configure PA1,PA0 as UART0
     GPIOA->GPIOPCTL= (GPIOA->GPIOPCTL&0xFFFFFF00)+0x00000011;
     GPIOA->GPIOAMSEL &= ~0x03;          // disable analog functionality on PA1,PA0
    IntCtrl_EnableIRQ(UART0_IRQn);
   }`
```

## and here is the handler code

and here I am trying to alter some flags that I will use them in the Game loop in the main

```
`void UART0_Handler(void)
   {
    if (UART0->MIS & UART_MIS_RXMIS) { // If a receive interrupt has occurred
        SET_BIT_PERIPH_BAND(UART0->ICR,UART_ICR_TXIC); // Clear the interrupt flag
        receivedChar = (uint8_t)UART0->DR; // Read the received character
                switch(receivedChar) {
                            case 'a':
                                    // Handle the 'a' key press
                                    moveLeft_Flag = TRUUE;
                                    break;
                            case 'd':
                                    moveRight_Flag = TRUUE;
                                break;
                            case ' ':
                                    fireBullet_Flag = TRUUE;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                SET_BIT_PERIPH_BAND(UART0->ICR,UART_ICR_RXIC); // Clear the interrupt flag
      }
    
    if (UART0->MIS & UART_MIS_TXMIS) { // If a transmit interrupt has occurred
        UART0->DR = receivedChar; // Send the character stored in the global variable c
         
     }

     }`
```

I tried to debug the code of the init and found that every value was written to the registers but when trying to write on the UART window I got nothing

Comment: Not sure what "write any character in the UART window" means, but I'll guess you have a terminal open on a PC and are typing into it. Check that the baud rate, number of data bits, parity and flow-control settings are the same on both sides.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I am using PUTTY and I am sure that the configuration is true because I tested it using polling instead of Interrupt and It is working

Comment: Maybe you haven't enabled the interrupt then. You might need to enable it both in the interrupt controller, and on the UART.

Comment: you polled the interrupt handler all the way up to the processor interrupt enable and then when you took the last step to the processor itself it is not working?  Or you just polled the uart and not the whole rest of the system?

Comment: @pmacfarlane I have enabled it here IntCtrl_EnableIRQ(UART0_IRQn);

Comment: @IbrahimYasser That is one place to enable it. You need to also tell the UART which events it should generate interrupts for.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I also turned on the Interrupt of UART peripheral for RX case here SET_BIT_PERIPH_BAND(UART0->IM,UART_IM_RXIM);

Comment: How are you determining that you don't receive a character? Using the debugger (with a breakpoint in the ISR)? Or because your code doesn't do what you want? Would recommend a breakpoint in the ISR to narrow it down.

Comment: @pmacfarlane of course I made a breakpoint in the start of the ISR and writing in PUTTY but It didn't jump to the ISR

Comment: I don't know how ISRs are done on this platform, but is it enough to just make a function like `UART0_Handler()`? Do you have to call a function to install an interrupt handler?

Comment: I QUIT I am gonna sleep